# Video stream is more zoomed than I'd like and isn't the same as the local stream view. How can I fix this?

Tags: agora.io

Using the Agora.io Video SDK v2.2.1. Below is an image of what happens. The video stream is zoomed in and there is a "big head" rather than the entire image.

[image: Example of what happens]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add below code before join channel this should help -

setParameters:@"{\"che.video.keep_prerotation\":false}"
setParameters:@"{\"che.video.local.camera_index\":1025}"

Refere the demo code :
https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Video-With-FaceUnity-iOS/blob/d777df2aac725bce120f9e8c4d599d026d2c9d79/AgoraWithFaceunity/Controllers/RoomViewController.m#L110