# Agora remote video too zoomed in

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I am using agora to live stream one to many. Hence I have one Broadcaster and multiple Audience in my code.

```
  await AgoraRtcEngine.enableWebSdkInteroperability(true);
  AgoraRtcEngine.setParameters('{\"che.video.lowBitRateStreamParameter\": 
  {\"width\":320,\"height\":180,\"frameRate\":15,\"bitRate\":140}, 
  {\"che.video.keep_prerotation\":false},{\"che.video.local.camera_index\":1025}}');
 await AgoraRtcEngine.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting);
 await AgoraRtcEngine.setClientRole(ClientRole.Audience);
 await AgoraRtcEngine.joinChannel(null, channelName, null, 0);
```

It works fine. But the problem is video is too zoomed in hence it's unusable .
There was one more question for this problem on stackoverflow :
[Video stream is more zoomed than I'd like and isn't the same as the local stream view. How can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377077/video-stream-is-more-zoomed-than-id-like-and-isnt-the-same-as-the-local-stream)

The accepted solution for this is:Please add below code before join channel this should help -

setParameters:@"{\"che.video.keep_prerotation\":false}" setParameters:@"{\"che.video.local.camera_index\":1025}"

Refere the demo code : https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Video-With-FaceUnity-iOS/blob/d777df2aac725bce120f9e8c4d599d026d2c9d79/AgoraWithFaceunity/Controllers/RoomViewController.m#L110

But for me this solution is not working.As you can see I have already added the parameters as suggested by the answer.
And even the link to github shows 404.
Can anyone please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the parameter you will have to add the following details along with your mentioned code:

```
setParameters("{"che.audio.live_for_comm":true}")
```

Also the zoomed out frame can be fixed by this:

1. you can set the video profile by calling

   setVideoEncoderConfiguration()

Through this you can set your video profile. You can get details about these profiles over here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1video_1_1_video_encoder_configuration.html#a50e755074e254026b51dfaa2e3dc91d9

2. You can also try defining the orientation to landscape or portrait and then see the result.
3. Also in your device settings if the screen size or text size is increased, change it back to default and try running it again.

Comment: thanks ! I changed the orientation to adaptive and it worked.